# Calculate values on value insert

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I want to create very simple JSF web page which I would like to use for price calculation:

```
<h:form>
    <h:outputText value="Number of Computers"/>

    <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="desktopClients_select" style="padding-top: 3px;" styleClass="text">
        <h:inputText id="desktopClients" value="#{pricingCalculator.computers}">
            <f:ajax event="change" render="@form" listener="#{pricingCalculator.calculateTotalPrice}"/>
        </h:inputText>
    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:outputText value="Email support incidents"/>

    <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="email_support_incidents" style="padding-top: 3px;" styleClass="text">
        <h:inputText id="email_support_incidents_text" value="#{pricingCalculator.emailSupportIncidents}">
            <f:ajax event="change" render="@form" listener="#{pricingCalculator.calculateTotalPrice}"/>
        </h:inputText>
    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:outputText value="Phone support incidents"/>

    <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="phone_support_incidents" style="padding-top: 3px;" styleClass="text">
        <h:inputText id="phone_support_incidents_text" value="#{pricingCalculator.phoneSupportIncidents}">
            <f:validateLongRange minimum="1" maximum="150" />
            <f:ajax event="change" render="@form" listener="#{pricingCalculator.calculateTotalPrice}"/>
        </h:inputText>
    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:outputText value="Total price"/>

    <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="total_price" style="padding-top: 3px;" styleClass="text">
        <h:outputText value="#{pricingCalculator.calculateTotalPrice}"/>
    </h:panelGroup>

    </h:panelGrid>

</h:form>
```

**Bean:**

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class PricingCalculator implements Serializable
{
    private int computers;
    private float emailSupportIncidents;
    private float phoneSupportIncidents;

    private float totalPrice;

    // Prices for each component and service    
    private final float computers_price = 299;
    private final float emailSupportIncidents_price = 300;
    private final float phoneSupportIncidents_price = 150;

    public String getCalculateTotalPrice()
    {
        totalPrice = (computers_price * computers)
            + (emailSupportIncidents_price * emailSupportIncidents)
            + (phoneSupportIncidents_price * phoneSupportIncidents);

        String result = Float.toString(totalPrice);
        return result;
    }

    public int getComputers()
    {
        return computers;
    }

    public void setComputers(int computers)
    {
        this.computers = computers;
    }

    public float getEmailSupportIncidents()
    {
        return emailSupportIncidents;
    }

    public void setEmailSupportIncidents(float emailSupportIncidents)
    {
        this.emailSupportIncidents = emailSupportIncidents;
    }

    public float getPhoneSupportIncidents()
    {
        return phoneSupportIncidents;
    }

    public void setPhoneSupportIncidents(float phoneSupportIncidents)
    {
        this.phoneSupportIncidents = phoneSupportIncidents;
    }

    public float getTotalPrice()
    {
        return totalPrice;
    }

    public void setTotalPrice(float totalPrice)
    {
        this.totalPrice = totalPrice;
    }
}
```

When I insert some value into the input fields I would like to recalculate the total price. I have now two issues: I get exception `serverError: class javax.el.MethodNotFoundException /pricing_calculator.xhtml @115,136 listener="#{pricingCalculator.calculateTotalPrice}": Method not found: com.web.common.PricingCalculator@22939533.calculateTotalPrice(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent)`

and when I insert new value previous one is set to zero. It's not remembered properly.

Comment: What part exactly of the exception didn't you understand? It says that it was expecting to find the in the message mentioned method, but you indeed don't have such one.

Answer (score 2):

@BalusC has already given you the answer, but to be more explicit, here's a quote from Oracle's Java EE 6 tutorial (which you should read) about **Method Expressions**:

> Method expressions can be used only in tag attributes and only in the
>   following ways:
>
> - With a single expression construct, where bean refers to a JavaBeans component and **method refers to a method of the JavaBeans**
>     component:
>
>   `<some:tag value="#{bean.method}"/>`
>
> [...]

That said, rename `getCalculateTotalPrice` to `calculateTotalPrice`

**Edit**: There's also an inconsistency between the expected signatures of the following method calls:

- `<f:ajax listener="#{pricingCalculator.calculateTotalPrice} .../>`
  which expects a `MethodExpression` refering to a `calculateTotalPrice(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent)` method as clearly stated by the `javax.el.MethodNotFoundException`

and

- `<h:outputText value="#{pricingCalculator.calculateTotalPrice}"/>` which expects a `java.lang.String` that can refer to a bean property, or the return value of a method call.

Here, the `<h:outputText>` value is probably meant to be set to the `totalPrice` property, so it should be: `<h:outputText value="#{pricingCalculator.totalPrice}"/>`

Comment: Check that `<h:outputText>`, too. OP basically made 2 mistakes in 1 with that getter method.